# Django list item in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I want to reach every item in the list to generate new video source which I included some of my code. For example I want to do something like `{{url_list.video_count}}` to change videos. How can I do that?

I am trying to play videos in my site. `{{url_list.0}}` is in my opinion perfect for starting. And in JavaScript I want to change source according to `{{url_list.video_count}}` to play other videos when first video has ended.

I basically want to have an invisible playlist.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var video_count = 1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video");
arr_length = {{ url_list.count }};
function run() {
    video_count++;
    if (video_count == arr_length) video_count = 0;
        nextVideo = "{{ url_list.1}}";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
    };
```

In views.py:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(VideoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['url_list'] = Video.objects.all().order_by("-order").values_list("url", flat=True)
    return context
```

In models.py:

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=Video)
def video_url_handler(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    instance.url = "media/video/%i.ogg" % instance.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Js:

```
var table = document.getElementById("playlist");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("li");
var values = $(cells).text()
var video_count = 0;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video");
arr_length = {{ url_list.count }};
function run(){
    video_count++;
    if (video_count == arr_length) video_count = 0;
    nextVideo = $(cells[video_count]).text();
    videoPlayer.src = "" + nextVideo;
    videoPlayer.play();
    };
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="playlist" style="display:none;">
<h2>Playlist</h2>
<ul>
{% for url in url_list %}
<li id="playlist-one">{{url}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

I did those and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should first convert your list to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) :

```
import json

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(VideoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    url_list = Video.objects.all().order_by("-order").values_list("url", flat=True)
    context['url_list'] = json.dumps(url_list)
    return context
```

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but I've never worked with video in JS. If you give more detail maybe I can assist further.

Comment: I tried your answer url_list is not defined error also I tried "url_list" and I get "U r l L i s t" also ı tried json.dumps(context) and ı got [u'media/video/2.ogg', u'media/video/1.ogg'] is not JSON serializable

Comment: Try adding "print(url_list)" right before context['url_list'] to see what happens.

Comment: I did your suggestion and [u'media/video/2.ogg', u'media/video/1.ogg']